# Why do I get a 400 error when i'm trying to edit an inline keyboard (node-telegram-bot-api)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I am making a message with a simple inline keyboard. The expected result would be that when I click on the button it changes together with the message text.

However the button doesn't change and i get this error:

```
TelegramError: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message
```

I am using the node-telegram-bot-api package.

The code that has to change my keyboard is:

```js
let info_message = {
    text: "some info boi",
    keyboard: {
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{ text: 'Start', callback_data: '!/start' }]
            ]
        }
    }
}

client.on("callback_query", async (cb) => {
    if (cb.data === "!/info") {
        const msg = cb.message;
        const opts = {
            chat_id: msg.chat.id,
            message_id: msg.message_id,
        };
        await client.editMessageReplyMarkup(info_message.keyboard, opts);
        await client.editMessageText(info_message.text, opts);
    }
})
```

Comment: which line of code throws that error? the error suggests you're sending something that "isn't modified" but the other end expects some change ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to edit a message without changing anything in it. If you need to use `editMessageText` or `editMessageReplyMarkup` but for some reason you don't change anything then wrap the code in a `try catch` block (you should always do that). And to remove the clock from the inline keyboard when you click, put some action in the `catch` block, for example `answerCallbackQuery`.

In the above example the user didn't pass the `reply_markup` parameter correctly, so the message didn't change in any way and the error `400 Bad Request: message is not modified` appeared.

[400 MESSAGE_NOT_MODIFIED](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.editMessage)

Comment: Probably that was the problem, thank you. By the way at the time I was really not that good at programming at all, hence the missing knowledge of try catches. I have fixed the problem long time ago but still I hope this answer will help other people too.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error.

The method `editMessageReplyMarkup()` requires the parameter
`replyMarkup`, A JSON-serialized object for an inline keyboard.

My mistake was that I gave the whole reply_markup while I was requested to give only the inline_keyboard. The code now looks like this:

```js
client.on("callback_query", async (cb) => {
    if (cb.data === "!/info") {
        const msg = cb.message;
        const opts = {
            chat_id: msg.chat.id,
            message_id: msg.message_id,
        };
        await client.editMessageReplyMarkup(info_message.keyboard.reply_markup, opts); // I gave info_message.keyboard.reply_markup as input, instead of info_message.keyboard
        await client.editMessageText(info_message.text, opts);
    }
})
```